# Show that $\bigtriangledown \vec{r} = \vec{1}$

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Show that $\bigtriangledown \vec{r} = \vec{1}$

My instructor put the r and 1 in bold. I am not sure what a bold one means. From my work I get $1ii + 1jj + 1zz$

Comment: If you calculate the derivative of $\vec{r}$ you should get the identity matrix, which may be what a bold one means. Note that $\nabla\cdot\vec{r}$ is something else, though.

Comment: A letter usually denotes that it is a vector instead of a scalar; although the arrow on top of the letter already denotes that it’s a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Given a vector-valued function $\mathbf{r}:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, where  $\mathbf{r}=\vec{r}=\langle x,y,z\rangle$, I wonder if your instructor meant to write the derivative of $\mathbf{r}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
D \mathbf{r} &= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
\partial_x(x) & \partial_y(x) & \partial_z(x) \\ 
\partial_x(y) & \partial_y(y) & \partial_z(y) \\ 
\partial_x(z) & \partial_y(z) & \partial_z(z) \\ 
\end{pmatrix} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}  
= \mathbf{1}, 
\end{align*}
$$
a matrix of partial derivatives of the component functions, 
where $\partial_x = \partial/\partial_x$.